# 401 Access denied due to invalid subscription key in Central India Region

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I've two Face API endpoints. One in US West and another in Central India. The one in US West works fine but the Central India endpoint is throwing 401 error.

> {"error":{"code":"Unspecified","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."}}

I've verified all the endpoint, keys, location etc as mentioned in the blog (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2017/05/17/http-401-access-denied-when-calling-azure-cognitive-services-apis/)

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

This is crazy! I deleted the resource and created it again and it started working. The only change I made was chose a new resource group instead of selecting an existing one. Gosh!